# python 2.7.5 released in May but not recognized by pythonbrew?

Tags: python, pythonbrew

pythonbrew failed some months ago to install 2.7.3 due to a weird compiler error that was never resolved.

Now I ran pythonbrew cleanup and it failed:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/Ceti/.pythonbrew/build/Python2.7.3/build/lib.macosx-10.8-x86_64-2.7/_AE.so'
```

Why did pythonbrew install files under my account with user root? I manually deleted the Python-2.7.3 directory.

Now I'm trying to install the latest 2.7 release using Python's brew but:

```
Ceti$ pythonbrew update
You are already running the installed latest version of pythonbrew.

Ceti$ pythonbrew install 2.7.4
ERROR: Unknown python version: `Python-2.7.4`
Ceti$ pythonbrew install 2.7.5
ERROR: Unknown python version: `Python-2.7.5`

Ceti$ pbi http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.5/Python-2.7.5.tgz
Downloading Python-2.7.5.tgz as /Users/Ceti/.pythonbrew/dists/Python-2.7.5.tgz
curl: (37) Couldn't open file /Users/Ceti/http%3A/www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.5/Python-2.7.5.tgz
ERROR: Failed to download.
Failed to fetch.


Ceti$ pbi /Users/Ceti/.pythonbrew/dists/Python-2.7.5.tgz
Use the previously fetched /Users/Ceti/.pythonbrew/dists/Python-2.7.5.tgz
Extracting Python-2.7.5.tgz into /Users/Ceti/.pythonbrew/build/Python-2.7.5

This could take a while. You can run the following command on another shell to track the status:
```

tail -f "/Users/Ceti/.pythonbrew/log/build.log"

```
Patching Python-2.7.5
ERROR: Failed to patch `/Users/Ceti/.pythonbrew/build/Python-2.7.5`.
1: failed to `(patch -p0 < "/Users/Ceti/.pythonbrew/patches/macosx/python27/patch-Modules- posixmodule.diff") >> '/Users/Ceti/.pythonbrew/log/build.log' 2>&1`
```

How can I install the latest release?

Comment: Ha, I see pythonbrew was updated to be deprecated so I quit using this approach.

Comment: It does install 2.7.5 comfortably now.